# How to define accountName The resource name of the account that owns the collection of ad clients

Tags: javascript, api, adsense-api

I'm trying to use Adsense management API in Google Sheets using apps script which runs with javascript.

I'm unable to define "accountName " even knowing
"This sample lists all of the ad clients for a given account. Specify the account as a resource name, for example, accounts/pub-12345."

documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/adsense#list_ad_clients

Here is the code

`

```
enter code here`/**
 * Logs available Ad clients for an account.
 *
 * @param {string} accountName The resource name of the account that owns the
 *     collection of ad clients.
 */
function listAdClients(accountName) {
  let pageToken;
  do {
    const response = AdSense.Accounts.Adclients.list(accountName, {
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    if (!response.adClients) {
      Logger.log('No ad clients found for this account.');
      return;
    }
    for (const adClient of response.adClients) {
      Logger.log('Found ad client for product "%s" with resource name "%s".',
          adClient.productCode, adClient.name);
      Logger.log('Reporting dimension ID: %s',
          adClient.reportingDimensionId ?? 'None');
    }
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epno7.png)

after declaring the function, add the accountName in the const response.